# Jquery Show/Hide div depending on multiple radio button group selection

Tags: jquery

I couldn't figure out how to show/hide div depending on multiple radio button selection. If both Question 1 and Question 2 selected as Yes, than div should be shown, in any other cases div should be hidden.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='q1']").click(function() {
    if ($('input[name=q1]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
      $("input[name='q2']").click(function() {
        if ($('input[name=q2]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
          $("#part2").show();
        } else {
          $("#part2").hide();
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#part2").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="hideshow" name="q1" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="test" name="q1" value="No" /> No
<br />
<input type="radio" class="hideshow2" name="q2" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="q2" value="No" /> No
<br />
<div id="part2" style="display:none; margin-top:10px;">
  TEXT
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/no_leaf/quL70mpk/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use only one `change` handler and one `if` to check you condition.
The `change` event will also be fired, when a label is clicked, therefore it might be better than the `click` event.
And when you bind the click handler for `q2` in the handler of `q1`, you bind it on every click on `q1` again.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='q1'], input[name='q2']").change(function() {
    if ($('input[name=q1]:checked').val() === "Yes" && $('input[name=q2]:checked').val() === "Yes") {
      $("#part2").show();
    } else {
      $("#part2").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="hideshow" name="q1" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="test" name="q1" value="No" /> No
<br />
<input type="radio" class="hideshow2" name="q2" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="q2" value="No" /> No
<br />
<div id="part2" style="display:none; margin-top:10px;">
  TEXT
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Correct, with `click` event it was always depended on `q1` no matter if it is Yes or No. Thank you very much @Sven.